# Call smart contract function by connecting contract address in hardhat (ethers)

Tags: blockchain, solidity, chai, nft, erc721

### Background of Problem:

I am developing an NFT Marketplace.
In its workflow, the admin (deployer of the smart contract) adds NFTs to the marketplace, and at that time these NFTs are owned by the **Marketplace** smart contract.

Now when a user comes to buy a particular NFT we have to transfer the ownership from the **smart contract address** to the **signer/wallet address**.

### Actual Problem:

While writing chai tests, I need to call the function `buyFromMarketplace` written in marketplace contract, which transfers the ownership of nft there. I am trying connecting the **marketplace** smart contract address (But I can't find any way to do it)
I've tried to do it this way (But I knew this won't work)

```
await nft.connect(marketplace).approve(addr1.address, 0);
```

Also tried to send a raw address while connecting to the NFT smart contract before calling `approve` by calling `marketplace.address`.

In [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71666255/how-to-transfer-a-nft-to-another-smart-contract), something similar is being done but NOT in testing

While a similar thing is done with ERC20 tokens [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70084327/sending-eth-from-contract-to-wallet-address).

**Edit:** I found the solution and posted in answers, maybe it helps someone in the future!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Answering my own question, so in the future, it may help someone else.

Well, after some struggle and @Tahlil's answer, I found the solution to this problem.

The actual problem was `buyFromMarketplace` function transfers nft's ownership from contract to the wallet/signer. So we were calling `nft.transfer` in it. Which need's owner/approved to call it but as mentioned in question intially nft is owned by `Marketplace` contract.

Actually we didn't needed to approve caller's account by calling `approve` marketplace contract address before calling `buyFromMarketplace`.

**Opinion:**

`connect` function of ethers hardhat should not allow connecting contract addresses, since we are dealing with accounts there.

**Fact:**

It works exaclty the same.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's possible. However, there is an easy fix. Add a function in the contract that calls the `approve` function. It would make sense if it could only be called by the admin of the contract (owner).

```
function approveNFT(address approveFor, uint256 tokenID) external onlyOwner{
   nftContract.approve(approveFor, tokenID) //assume "nftContract" is the ERC721 contract address
}
```

Now you can adjust your code like this:

```
await nft.connect(owner).approveNFT(addr1.address, 0);
```